# Does the time field in a csv exported nagios XI State History Report represent the last time a service was checked for that time period in the report?

Tags: date, nagios

I've done an export of the State History Report in nagios XI to export to a CSV for a specified time period.  I get back the fields time, host, service, statechange, statetype, currentattempt, maxattempts, laststate, lasthardstate, and information.

Does the time field which contains date and time refer to the state of the service specified on that row for that host at the time it was checked last?

Answer (score 0):

Date / Time: Date that a notification occurred.